# What is the point of this C# Dictionary<,> optimization?

Tags: c#

I'm using C# 4.0. "Optimize code" in Visual Studio is turned on.

Consider the following code, in a class:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

public void IncrementDictionary(int key) {
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
        dictionary[key] = 1;
    } else {
        dictionary[key]++;
    }
}
```

Here, a call to `IncrementDictionary` does one of two things:

- If no value exists for `key`, then a value is created and initialized to 1.
- If a value exists, the value is incremented by 1.

Now watch what happens when I use ILSpy to decompile the result:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

public void IncrementDictionary(int key) {
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
        dictionary[key] = 1;
        return;
    }
    Dictionary<int, int> dictionary2;
    (dictionary2 = dictionary)[key] = dictionary2[key] + 1;
}
```

**Note:** In the actual production code using this, the optimizer/compiler also creates: `int key2 = key;` and uses `key2` in the final line.

Ok, `var` has been replaced by `Dictionary<int, int>`, which is expected. And the `if` statement was simplified to add a `return` instead of using an `else`.

**But why the heck was a new reference to the original dictionary created?**

Comment: Important note: no second dictionary is created. Rather, a second reference to the existing dictionary is taken.

Comment: @Jon: Right, my mistake.

Comment: The ILSpy you posted isn't an exact representation of what's happening in the CIL code directly. It's possible this is a bug or imperfection in the CIL-to-C# decompiler. Can you post the CIL so we can be certain?

Comment: Yep, i think there's a real danger of taking decompiled code too literally.

Comment: @David: If you're referring to the lack of `this` when accessing `dictionary`, then that's my fault. I originally had the dictionary as a local variable but realized that that would be pointless, so I *tried* to fix it by hand :)

Comment: Is anyone willing to point a copy of Reflector at the code to see if it is just an ILSpy quirk?

Comment: @SimpleCoder decompiled it with Reflector, looks almost the same, but it kept the `else`

Comment: @SimpleCoder I think you may have mixed up your code blocks: they're both showing the ILSpy result. :)  Kinda hard to compare now!

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Now it is. It was in a class, but I never updated that line when I "fixed" it (see above).

Comment: Sorry, can you post the generated IL?

Comment: @JamesManning: Chris Sinclair posted it below in his answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing it could be to avoid a race condition where if you have:

`dictionary[i] = dictionary[i] + 1`

It's not atomic.  The `dictionary` being assigned to could change *after* you got the value and incremented.

Imagine this code:

```
public Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

public void Increment()
{
    int newValue = dictionary[0] + 1;
    //meanwhile, right now in another thread: dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    dictionary[0] = newValue; //at this point, "dictionary" is actually pointing to a whole new instance
}
```

With the local variable assignment they have, it looks more like this to avoid the condition:

```
public void IncrementFix()
{
    var dictionary2 = dictionary;
    //in another thread: dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    //this is OK, dictionary2 is still pointing to the ORIGINAL dictionary
    int newValue = dictionary2[0] + 1;
    dictionary2[0] = newValue;
}
```

Note that it doesn't fully satisfy all thread-safe requirements.  For example, in this case, we start incrementing the value, but the `dictionary` reference on the class has changed to a whole new instance.  But if you need that higher level of thread safety, then you need to implement your own aggressive synchronization/locking, which is generally outside the scope of compiler optimizations.  However this one, from what I can tell, doesn't really add any big hit (if any) to processing and avoids this condition.  This might especially be the case if `dictionary` is a *property* not a field as it is in your example, in which case it would definitely be an optimization to not resolve the property getter twice. (By any chance, is your actual code using a property for the dictionary rather than the field you posted?)

EDIT: Well, for a simple method:

```
public void IncrementDictionary() 
{
    dictionary[0]++;
}
```

The IL reported from LINQPad is:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldfld       UserQuery.dictionary
IL_0007:  dup         
IL_0008:  stloc.0     
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000A:  ldloc.0     
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000C:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.Int32>.get_Item
IL_0011:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0012:  add         
IL_0013:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.Int32>.set_Item
IL_0018:  nop         
IL_0019:  ret
```

I'm not entirely sure (I'm not an IL wiz), but I think the `dup` call essentially doubles up the same dictionary reference on the stack so regardless both the get and set calls will point to the same dictionary.  Perhaps this is just how ILSpy represents it as C# code (it's more or less the same at least as behaviour goes).  I think.  Please correct me if I'm wrong because, like I said, I don't know IL like the back of my hand yet.

EDIT: Gotta run, but the final gist of it is: `++` and `+=` are not an atomic operations and is actually a good deal more complicated in executed instructions than as depicted in C#.  As such, to make sure that that each of the get/increment/set steps are performed on the same dictionary instance (as you would expect and require from the C# code) a local reference to the dictionary is made to avoid running the field "get" operation twice which could result to pointing to a new instance.  How ILSpy depicts that all that work involved with a indexed += operation is up to it.

Comment: Nope, `dictionary2` is still pointing to the original dictionary.

Comment: Right. `Increment()` controls `dictionary2`: it is a local reference to the original dictionary.

Comment: Your point about not resolving the property getter twice is very relevant, and actually would not be an optimization but what you would intuitively expect when calling dictionary[key]++ (ie. if the property has some side effect, it should only happen once)

Comment: `...we start incrementing the value...` Actually, won't `(dictionary2 = dictionary)` execute before anything else, since it's in parentheses?

Comment: @SimpleCoder yeah, it will be assigned first.  That's my equivalent `var dictionary2 = dictionary1;` line.  @d--b, it's a big deal IF `dictionary` is a _property_, if it's a field then there isn't an optimization (I think) in that regard.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Even in a single-threaded scenario, the compiler has no way of knowing whether the `Dictionary<,>` "indexed get" function will alter any field of any object (including `this.dictionary`).  Not exactly a "race condition", but an issue nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit messed up what you were trying to show, but the reason that `dictionary[key]++` makes a temporary copy of `dictionary` is that it has no way of knowing whether the indexed getter for `Dictionary<int,int>` will change field `dictionary`.  The spec indicates that even if field `dictionary` is changed during the indexed get, the indexed put will still be executed on the same object.

BTW, .net really should have (and still should) provide a means by which classes can expose properties as `ref`.  It would be possible for `Dictionary` to provide methods `ActOnValue(TKey key, ActionByRef<TValue> action)` and `ActOnValue<TParam>(TKey key, ActionByRef<TValue, TParam> action, ref TParam param)` (assuming `ActionByRef<T>` is like `Action<T>` but the parameter declared `ref`, and likewise `ActionByRef<T1,T2>`).  If it did, one could perform a read-modify-write on a collection object without having to index into the collection twice.  Unfortunately, there's no standard convention for exposing properties in such fashion, nor is there any language support.

Comment: Ok thanks. What you say makes sense- I had never thought of that.